# DataParsingError with Sage Accounting API authorisation request

Tags: php, rest

[UPDATED code based on CBroe answers]

I am using the Sage Developer documentation on connecting to the Sage accounting API via a PHP class but am coming up against the following error:

```
'{"$severity":"error","$dataCode":"DataParsingError","$message":"The data you sent could not be processed.","$source":"Proxy"}'
```

I have created an app and set the callback addresses, secrets etc., Using their guide on the authentication system, but I am clearly missing something. https://developer.sage.com/accounting/guides/authenticating/authentication/

My script successfully runs the first part, and we are redirected to authorise the connection; however, I get the error above when redirecting back to the callback URL.

My class is below:

```
<?php

class Sage
{
    private $clientId;
    private $clientSecret;
    private $accessToken;
    
    public function __construct() {

        $this->clientId = '37d7c52a-2550-4685-b2e0-e03146b370f7/641d33eb-83d1-4b3f-9051-6ddcde064ec9';
        $this->clientSecret = 'eie%vSrnw8sT|/(X;SIz';
    }

    function authorizeSageAccountingApp()
    {
        $authorizationUrl = 'https://www.sageone.com/oauth2/auth/central?filter=apiv3.1&country=gb&locale=en_GB';
        $clientId = $this->clientId;
        $redirectUri = 'http://localhost/sailadventure-new/tests/callback';
        $scopes = 'full_access'; // or 'readonly' if applicable

        $authorizationUrl .= '&response_type=code';
        $authorizationUrl .= '&client_id=' . urlencode($clientId);
        $authorizationUrl .= '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($redirectUri);
        $authorizationUrl .= '&scope=' . urlencode($scopes);
        $authorizationUrl .= '&state=159786325';

        header('Location: ' . $authorizationUrl);
        exit();
    }

    function handleCallback()
    {
        if (isset($_GET['code'])) {

            // Initialize cURL
            $curl = curl_init();

            // Create the URL
            $url = 'https://oauth.accounting.sage.com/token';

            
            $clientSecret = $this->clientSecret;
            $authCode = $_GET['code'];
            $data = array(
                'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                'client_id' => $this->clientId,
                'client_secret' => $this->clientSecret,
                'code' => $authCode,
                'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost/sailadventure-new/tests/callback'
            );

            curl_setopt($curl,  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            curl_setopt($curl,  CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($curl,  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
            curl_setopt($curl,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl,  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
            [
                'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            ]);

            // Execute the request
            $response = curl_exec($curl);

            if (curl_errno($curl)) {
                $error = curl_error($curl);
                return $error;
            }

            curl_close($curl);
            echo '<pre>' . var_export($response, true) . '</pre>';
            
        }
    }
}
```

And the URLs are using my custom MVC system but essentially look like this.

```
<?php
class Tests extends Controller {

  public function __construct() {

  }

  //localhost/sailadventure-new/tests
  public function index() {

    $sage = new Sage();
    $sage->authorizeSageAccountingApp();

  }

  //localhost/sailadventure-new/tests/callback
  public function callback() {

    $sage = new Sage();
    $sage->handleCallback();

  }

  //localhost/sailadventure-new/tests/continue
  public function continue() {

    $sage = new Sage();

  }
}
```

Below a screenshot of the app details in the Sage Developer console.

[image]

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: You are sending JSON, but the endpoint wants `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: Ah good, spot, so changing 

curl_setopt($curl,  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
            [
                'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            ]); 

still returns the same error. Or do I need to change this somewhere else - I'm afraid a little bit of a neewb when it comes to Curl requests.

Comment: You need to stop encoding the actual data you are sending as JSON, as well.

Comment: I've removed the encoding (see updated post) as JSON and just sending $data straight into the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS but still receiving the same. Thanks for pointers so far

Comment: The `redirect_uri` value you are using in that second request is also most likely wrong; usually with OAuth, that needs to be the _exact_ same value you used, when creating the authorization URL.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is correct, I've added a screenshot of the callback URLs as set in the developer console.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it isn't :-) The token exchange endpoint doesn't need to redirect anyone, anywhere. The only reason this parameter gets passed to that endpoint, is to increase security - the code is only supposed to get exchanged for a token, if that code was acquired in a process that redirected the user back to that particular redirect_uri in the first place. Passing any other redirect_uri value, will make this exchange fail.

Comment: Ah ok, so that needs to be set as the URL of the page it's running from? Or removed?

Comment: No, not removed, it's a mandatory parameter - but you need to provide the exact same value you used in the first step, so that would be `http://localhost/sailadventure-new/tests/callback` here in your situation.

Comment: cool, I've changed the URL to match the first (and updated the code above) but still getting the same message. '{"$severity":"error","$dataCode":"DataParsingError","$message":"The data you sent could not be processed.","$source":"Proxy"}'
Thanks so much for your time and help

Comment: When you pass an array to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, it makes a multipart/formdata request. Try and use `http_build_query` to transform your parameter array into a query string format.

Comment: Btw. if those client id and secret you have shown above a real, then you should go and reset your secret now - otherwise, everyone reading this question here, will be able to use/abuse them. (Editing the question alone won't help, users with enough privilege will still be able to see the edit history.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue was in encoding & decoding the code returned by Sage in the URL of the callback.

I added the following, and everything fell into place, along with various syntax and code issues pointed out by CBroe.

```
$authCode = $_GET['code'];

$authCode = preg_replace("/%u([0-9a-f]{3,4})/i","&#x\\1;",urldecode($authCode)); 

$authCode = html_entity_decode($authCode,null,'UTF-8');
```

Full code shown below for anyone else.

```
<?php

class Sage
{
    private $clientId;
    private $clientSecret;
    private $accessToken;
    
    public function __construct() {

        $this->clientId = 'XXXX';
        $this->clientSecret = 'XXXX';
    }

    function authorizeSageAccountingApp()
    {
        $authorizationUrl = 'https://www.sageone.com/oauth2/auth/central?filter=apiv3.1&country=gb&locale=en_GB';
        $clientId = $this->clientId;
        $redirectUri = 'http://localhost/sailadventure-new/tests/callback';
        $scopes = 'full_access'; // or 'readonly' if applicable

        $authorizationUrl .= '&response_type=code';
        $authorizationUrl .= '&client_id=' . urlencode($clientId);
        $authorizationUrl .= '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($redirectUri);
        $authorizationUrl .= '&scope=' . urlencode($scopes);
        $authorizationUrl .= '&state=159786325';

        header('Location: ' . $authorizationUrl);
        exit();
    }

    function handleCallback()
    {
        if (isset($_GET['code'])) {

            // Initialize cURL
            $curl = curl_init();

            // Create the URL
            $url = 'https://oauth.accounting.sage.com/token';

            $clientSecret = $this->clientSecret;

            $authCode = $_GET['code'];
            $authCode = preg_replace("/%u([0-9a-f]{3,4})/i","&#x\\1;",urldecode($authCode)); 
            $authCode = html_entity_decode($authCode,null,'UTF-8');

            $data = array(
                'client_id' => $this->clientId,
                'client_secret' => $this->clientSecret,
                'code' => $authCode,
                'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',               
                'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost/sailadventure-new/tests/callback'
            );

            curl_setopt($curl,  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
            curl_setopt($curl,  CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($curl,  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
            curl_setopt($curl,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl,  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
            [
                'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Accept: application/json',
            ]);

            // Execute the request
            $response = curl_exec($curl);

            if (curl_errno($curl)) {
                $error = curl_error($curl);
                return $error;
            }

            curl_close($curl);
            echo '<pre>' . var_export($response, true) . '</pre>';
            
        }
    }
}
```